# Full type names in QMetaMethod

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to receive full type names in QMetaMethod of return type and or argument types?

Example,

```
namespace N1 {
namespace N2 {
    class C1: public QObject {
      Q_OBJECT
    };
}
}


class C2: public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
  typedef N1::N2::C1 C1T;

  Q_INVOKABLE void foo(C1T c1); 
};

QMetaMethod method;

// some logic to find method void foo(C1T) of C2

auto name  = method.parameterNames(); // return "C1T"

auto name2 = C1T::staticMetaObjec.className()  // return "N1::N2::C1"
```

Is it possilbe to find out the full name of method's parameter name, not "C1T", but "N1::N2::C1", or at least "C1"? The same problem with namespaces, that if C2 is in N1 namespace and I use N2::C1 as an argument type, it returns "N2::C1", can I have "N1::N2::C2" ?

Comment: Short answer: no. `moc` uses exactly the type (exactly as in *as you type it*) when extracting these information. The only workaround is to complete specify types in methods (and other things) that `moc` extracts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moc does not understand C++ type system. To moc, a type is a string, and is only equivalent to another type if the strings match. You have to stick to one way of representing the parameter type, and use that.